# How can I find out more about the semaphore handles reported by handle.exe?

Tags: windows, semaphore, handle

I have a large multithreaded C++ program running on Windows 7 which went from 2182 to 6971 semaphore handles overnight according to the output of handle.exe. If I look at the output of 'handle.exe -a -p [processid]' I get a bunch of lines like:

```
 7BC0: Semaphore     
 7BCC: Semaphore     
 7BD0: Semaphore
```

How can I find out where these semaphores are getting created? Is there something I can search for in Visual Studio?

Comment: Use Application Verifier: http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2011/12/19/how-to-troubleshoot-a-handle-leak.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It is just link soup.  You can write a better answer than me by sharing your experience using App Verifier.